# How to implement pipeline design pattern using reactive webflux?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have two simple interfaces called `Processor` and `SeedPreProcessor` and they are defined like:

Processor:

```
public interface Processor<I, O> {

    Mono<O> process(I input);
}
```

SeedPreProcessor:

```
public interface SeedPreProcessor<D> extends Processor<D, D> {

    /**
     * Specify the location of this processor in the pipeline.
     *
     * @return the order
     */
    Integer order();

    String name();
}
```

and a `PipeLine` defined like:

```
public class PipeLine {

    private final List<SeedPreProcessor<PreProcessorDocument>> allProcessors;

    public PipeLine(List<SeedPreProcessor<PreProcessorDocument>> allProcessors) {
        this.allProcessors = new ArrayList<>(allProcessors);
        this.allProcessors.sort(comparingInt(SeedPreProcessor::order));
    }

    public Mono<PreProcessorDocument> execute(String url) {
        log.info("Start processing URL = {}", url);
        var initial = new PreProcessorDocument(url);
        return Flux
                .fromIterable(allProcessors)
                .map(proc -> proc.process(initial).t) // my problem is here
    }
}
```

I want to for a `inital PreProcessorDocument` to execute all the `SeedPreProcessor` in the
list `allProcessors` one by one.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So the input for second processor should be the output of first one in chain? Or how should it work?

Comment: @MichałKrzywański  first part of your question yes. second part, do you mean make the input of processor Mono?

Comment: why not simply `        var initial = new PreProcessorDocument(url);
        Mono<PreProcessorDocument> m = Mono.just(initial);
        for(SeedPreProcessor<PreProcessorDocument> p : allProcessors) {
            m = m.flatMap(p::process);
        }
        return m;`

Comment: @MichałKrzywański thank you so much! you are hero, Michal please at least post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `foreach` loop and `flatMap` operator will do the trick :

```
public Mono<PreProcessorDocument> execute(String url) {
    var initial = new PreProcessorDocument(url);
    Mono<PreProcessorDocument> m = Mono.just(initial);

    for (SeedPreProcessor<PreProcessorDocument> p : allProcessors) {
        m = m.flatMap(p::process);
    }
    return m;
}
```